# State not updating with useState set method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to learn hooks and try to update the state using onMouseEnter and Leave events, but the state in `isFlip.flipStat` doesn't change, it used for flag to flipping the card using ReactCardFlip components. The only issues here is my state doesn't change when handleMouse function trigger, maybe anyone can help. Thanks in advance.

Here's my code :

````
function OurServices() {
  const [isFlip, setFlip] = useState([])
  const listServices = [
    {
      "title": "title",
      "img": "img.jpg",
      "desc": "lorem ipsum"
    }
  ]
  
  function handleMouse(key) {
    let newArr = [...isFlip]
    newArr[key].flipStat = !newArr[key].flipStat
    setFlip(newArr)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    listServices.map((x) => (
      x.flipStat = false
    ))
    setFlip(listServices)
  })
             return (
               {isFlip.map((x, key) => (
                  <div key={key} onMouseEnter={() => handleMouse(key)} onMouseLeave={() => handleMouse(key)}>
                    <div className={styles.card} >
                      <div className={styles.card_body+" p-xl-0 p-lg-0 p-md-1 p-sm-1 p-0"}>
                        <ReactCardFlip isFlipped={x.flipStat} flipDirection="horizontal">
                          <div className="row">
                            <div className={"col-xl-12 text-center "+styles.services_ic}>
                              <img className="img-fluid" src={x.img} width="72" height="72" alt="data-science" />
                            </div>
                            <div className={"col-xl-11 mx-auto text-center mt-4 "+styles.services_desc}>{x.title}</div>
                          </div>
                          
                          <div className="row">
                            <div className={"col-xl-12 text-center "+styles.services_ic}>
                              {parse(x.desc)}
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </ReactCardFlip>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                ))}
               )```
````

Comment: Have you checked if the handleMouse function is called at all?

Comment: @GustavPSvensson yes is called, I can log the state also but and its seems the state doesn't change

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is in your useEffect,

```
useEffect(() => {
   listServices.map((x) => (
       x.flipStat = false
   ))
   setFlip(listServices)
})
```

you are setting `listServices` as the isFlip array. But Array.map() method doesn't update the source array. You need to write like this,

```
useEffect(() => {
   const updatedArr = listServices.map((x) => (
       x.flipStat = false
       return x;
   ))
   setFlip(updatedArr)
})
```

And can you log newArr after this line `let newArr = [...isFlip]` and see if that array has all the items? It should help you debug the issue.

**Update:**
Try creating new array while setting the state,

```
function handleMouse(key) {
   let newArr = [...isFlip]
   newArr[key].flipStat = !isFlip[key].flipStat
   setFlip([...newArr])
}
```

Comment: here's the screenshot after I log the variable https://ibb.co/QKkDT2m

Comment: @dev0910, updated the answer please check.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is apparently from my code to adding `flipsStat` key to the `listServices` variable, to solving this I change the mapping way to this :

```
listServices.map((x) => ({
  ...x, flipStat: false
}))
```

Thanks for @sabbir.alam to reminds me for this.